# Magento2 - Getting Grouped and Configurable Product ID from Simple Product Id

Tags: magento2.3, simple-product, grouped-products

I am trying to get a `Grouped product ID` (and then the grouped product URL, but I can do this) from a `Simple product` which is part of this grouped product.

I tried the following:

`$parents = $product->getTypeInstance()->getParentIdsByChild($productId);`

Without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this way:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $groupedProduct,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->groupedProduct = $groupedProduct;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
      * $childId Child Item id
      */
    public function getGroupedProductId($childId) {
     return $this->groupedProduct->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    }
```